# "An unknown error has occurred" deploying google cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Some of our cloud storage buckets with "appspot" in the name were deleted.

This in turn broke a cloud function we had running. The issue is that now I'm getting "an unknown error has occurred" when I try to deploy a new function.

I've tried to just deploy the basic "hello world" function to eliminate any possible issues with our code, but same response. I don't see any errors or other issues when I view the logs.

Is there any way to get back to a good state? We're in the lucky position that it was the only function running, so we don't have to worry about damaging other functions.

Comment: If you disable and then enable a service (API), the resources required (buckets, service accounts, etc) are created if missing. I have not verified this with Cloud Functions with your problem. In the Console or via the CLI look for `cloudfunctions.googleapis.com`.  Double-check that you have the deployment files (source code, etc) first for each function that you deployed.

Comment: There should be logs related to the deployment, they might contain some details about the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, I think you need a "deployed" cloud function first to really update it properly (unfortunately that error does not explain what really is the issue).

Although my issue was trying to use a cloud source repository instead of inline code, maybe it is related.

First deploy a new cloud function with base code , or duplicated one (even if it has error) then try to update it with inline code , or upload zip file or use cloud source repository